# Rails - notice is visible if CSS property width or padding is set

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

There is usual `<%=flash[:notice] %>` in layoyt.
When I tried to add it some styling, I faced such trouble. For example:

```
 text-align: center;
 background: #fde073;
```

If no notice were provided with redirect, nothing on the page, as expected.

But if I add `padding` or `height` to CSS, it shows notice(no text, but background color) even if no notice were provided with redirect.

I can fix it with JS, but it seems quite ugly to me. Any other options?

Comment: Just don't render that div if there's no notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest skipping rendering of notice div when notice isn't present. Like this:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class='notice'><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```